# What tools can I use for Django Testing Automation?

Tags: django, unit-testing, continuous-integration, django-testing

I'm looking into automating a test runner which would do the following things daily (or hourly or whenever I want basically):

1. Pull the latest code from a git repository.
2. Run the Django test suite or something like Nose.
3. Run Selenium tests.
4. Give Pass/Fail and coverage statistics via a web interface.
5. Email developers in the case of failures.

What kind of setups are out there? I've seen some blog posts, but many are pre-Django 1.1 and I know that the test suite has been improved significantly with that release, so I'm curious what the latest and best options out there are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd take a look at ponybuild, it's the replacement for buildbot that Titus Brown has been working on, and Jacob Kaplan-Moss is already looking at for django.  http://github.com/ctb/pony-build/network

Comment: That looks like a neat system. I'll be keeping an eye on it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like DJango itself uses [buildbot](http://buildbot.net/)

Answer (score 1):

[Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) is a really good tool for something like this. It doesn't have any specific support for django (that I know of), it's more of a general purpose tool. It has a plugin model, and it has plugins for git, selenium and cobetura, among other things. It also has a python plugin for running python scripts. and support for sending emails when things go wrong.